# String is always + 1 in length when it is entered in with the keyboard rather than set as a value in code

Tags: c, server, inet

So I am trying to write a program that will return the ip address of an entered domain name. The program is much bigger than that but it is this specific functionality that is not working.

After hours and hours of testing why the inet_ntoa was giving me a segmentation fault I decided to hard code the value "www.google.com" instead of typing it. WALA it worked! but why? I suspected that it was looking for "www.google.com\n" so I created a little funcitonality to account for that and delete the end of the string so that it would just be "www.google.com". Well that didn't work, to see if the two strings were equal I did a check. I found out that infact the hardcoded "www.google.com" and the typed in "www.google.com" were infact not the same. So i outputted both strings length. Turns out that the one that is typed in is always + 1 the one that is hardcoded.

Can someone explain this?

Here is my minimally representing example code.

```
    char buffer[2048];
    struct hostent *hen;
    int i = 0;

    //buffer is recieved by the client it is written to buffer like
    //while((buffer[n++] = getchar() != '\n')
    //then this server reads it. 

    while(buffer[i] != '\n'){
        //            strncat(b, &buffer[i], 100);
        i++;
    }
    i = i-2;
    char b[i];
    i = 0;
    while(buffer[i] != '\n'){
        strncat(b, &buffer[i], 1);
        i++;
    }
    int t = i;
    i = 0;
    while(i != t+1){
        printf("%c", b[i]);
        i++;
    }


    char *e = "www.google.com";
    if(e == b){
        printf("THEY EQUAL");

    } else {
        printf("THEY DON'T AND IM DUMB\n");
        printf("LENGTH OF E: %d\n", strlen(e));
        printf("LENGTH OF B: %d\n", strlen(b));
    }
    printf("here is: %s\n", e);

    hen=gethostbyname(e);
    if(hen==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Host not found \n");
    }
    printf("Hostname is %s \n",hen->h_name);
    printf("IP address is %s \n",inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hen->h_addr)));
```

Comment: `e == b` does not compare whether two strings are equal, that is done via `strcmp`

Comment: I am suspecting that it contains «\r» in the end. Can you please check this and tell me if that does something?

Comment: you are correct, but it still doesn't explain why b strlen is == to 15 and e strlen == 14

Comment: Since you know that it is one element longer you can just print out the numeric value of the extra element and check what ASCII (or whichever encoding you use) character it represents - that should help you figure out what is going on

Comment: @UnholySheep So, I tried that. Here are the results: at b[i] the value is m. at b[i-2] the value is o, and the value of b[i-1] is o. LOL, yes I typed it in correctly every time www.google.com

Comment: @MZ97 tried to check for \r and that produced wild results like machine code and the string length of that string would be like 50 or 67

Comment: should I just restart my computer?

Comment: I don't see where in this code you add the null termination character into `b`

Comment: Can you please print the ASCII values of all chars inside the string? You can do this by typecasting char to int

Comment: @UnholySheep I don't it is in buffer[2048]

Comment: If `b` is not null-terminated then passing it into functions that expect it to be (such as `strlen`)  invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: @MZ97 ASCII: 121191191194610311111110310810146991111090

Comment: WEIRD!! it says the first character is a 'y' according to ascii

Comment: Please add space between each char

Comment: @UnholySheep using strncmp(e, b, 14) == 0 does not work they do not equal still.

Comment: @MZ97 Sorry I see now how that could produce dumb results excuse my ignorance here is the space delimited version: 12 119 119 119 46 103 111 111 103 108 101 46 99 111 109 0

Comment: @MZ97 had the i wrong I was testing other things disregard the zero at the end should be: 12 119 119 119 46 103 111 111 103 108 101 46 99 111 109

Comment: @MZ97 So, did some more tests and figured out that at b[0] it prints nothing, unless I convert it to ascii in which case it prints 12. I am still confused as to why though.

Comment: Alright there’s no problem in this. The ASCII code 012 is called Form Feed (page break), which basically means it’s telling us that the following content is part of a new page. You might try to remove the first char, and you’re good to go!

Comment: @MZ97 If I initialize b with different I-n then the ascii value at the front goes down or up with the n so b[i-1] ascii might be 13 b[i] ascii might be 14

Comment: @MZ97 If you wanna put the above as an answer I will accept. It worked using that

Comment: Im not sure if changing the pointer of b would work. Did you try? I deleted the comment

Comment: @MZ97 Yeah changing the pointer worked

Comment: Thats good, I will try to make an answer so others in the future may benefit from this question

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(buffer[i] != '\n'){
        i++;
    }
    i = i-2;
    char b[i];
```

Imagine a simple "1234\n" as input.

```
Before: i == 0;
After '1': i == 1 because buffer[0] == '1';
After '2': i == 2 because buffer[1] == '2';
After '3': i == 3 because buffer[2] == '3';
After '4': i == 4 because buffer[3] == '4';
After '\n': i == 4 because buffer[4] == '\n' and we DON'T ENTER THE LOOP BODY.
```

And you allocate b[2] instead of b[5] ("1234" and the null-term!)

You simply write to random areas of the stack, corrupt memory, overwrite other variables (and they overwrite the end of your line later).

Comment: It will equal 5 at the end there, and it should be i-1 you are correct this is a result of me not knowing at all what is going on and testing random things the problem still persists whether its b[i], b[i-1], b[i-2]

Comment: It should be i+1. Body length and the null-term. It's while() loop, not do{}while(). And after you damaged the memory content, you can't rely on any printed logs. They can show any random data from random memory areas (and they seem to do so, due to comments).

Comment: ok so let me think of this if the string I am trying to put into a char is "1234" there is 4 characters there right well if i == 4 then that means if we make a char like this: char b[4] you now have 0 - 4 chars in that array of chars. 0 - 4 IS DRUM ROLL PLEASE: 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4. Therefore you are over allocating where as if you you do i - 1 you have allocated the exact amount needed. And thats just using I. you are saying add 1 to i making it b[5] over allocating by two slots.

Comment: I do appreciate you trying to help though.